# Derivative Notation Question (Contravariant vs. Covariant)

Tags: notation, partial-derivative

I know how to write a covariant derivative in Leibniz notation:
$$\partial^\mu\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$$
Does that mean that a contravariant derivative in Leibniz notation would be
$$\partial_\mu\equiv \frac{\partial}{\partial x_\mu}\tag{Does this expression even make sense?}$$
Another guess: $\partial_\mu\equiv dx_\mu$. The idea is to not have to write something like this:
$$g_{\mu\nu}\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\mu}$$
Is there a shorthand that does not write out the metric tensor explicitly, i.e. with the raising and lowering of indices? or does this not exist, since no one writes einstein-notation partials in Leibniz form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my Electrodynamics book, 
$$\partial _{\mu} = g_{\mu \nu}\partial ^{\nu}$$
where $g_{\mu \nu}$ is metric tensor.

Comment: I was wondering how to write that in the fractional leibniz notation, or if such a thing even exists

Comment: @Dave i have never seen it being used. A quick google search on "covariant derivative" leads to wikipedia and "contravariant derivative" leads to other forums. And I am in no position to claim it does not exist.

Comment: Ahh - thanks for letting me know though - I guess I'll have to stick to the $\partial_\mu$ notation.

Comment: @Dave sure you are welcome :) good luck for torture.